# Overload path functions with different @QueryParams

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to have multiple functions for the same GET Path.

As well i would like my web service to "find" these functions if and only if the query parameters match the parameters in the URL String.

For example:

I have the `Path("/myGET")`

And for that path i would like to have 2 functions:

> ```
> @GET  
> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> @TypeHint(TagSets.class)
> public Response getTagSets(@QueryParam("entityId") Integer entityId)
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```

And

> ```
> @GET  
> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> @TypeHint(TagSets.class)
> public Response getTagSets(){
>     ...
> }
> ```

Right now i am getting an error:

> SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
>     SEVERE: Producing media type conflict. The resource methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response<...>.getTagSets(java.lang.Integer) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response<...>.getTagSets(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer) can produce the same media type
>     SEVERE: Producing media type conflict. The resource methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response<...>.getTagSets() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response <...>.getTagSets(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer) can produce the same media type

So first:
Is there any way to achieve what i want to do here..

second:
If this is available, is there any way that a path will be found if and only if the query parameters match exactly what is requested in the function? for example if the same path will be called with `@QueryParam("differentParam")` it will not reach any of the 2 functions.

Third:
If there is no way to do this with Jersey is there a way to do it with any other frame work?.

**IMPORTANT:
As people that answer the question think that i am looking for a work around and not a solution. today i am using 1 function and checking the parameters and invoking what i need from this (that is what i used before i posted the question). But what i am looking for is maybe using the frameworks power to save me the trouble**

Thanks.

Comment: I think you,ll have to do it in a single method and programatically decide what other method to call based on the presence of the query parameters. I don‘t think this can be decided solely based on query params.

Comment: All the answers are referring to my current implementation. So i understand from you all that there is no way to do what i am looking for with jersey... do you know if there is way to do it with spring?

Comment: You asked for a single method having different query parameters, and my answer is using Jersey. What exactly are you looking for? Clarify your question.

Comment: No. that's not what i asked for.... read the question again

Answer (score 6):

A resource is uniquely defined by its **path**, and not by its params. Two resources you defined have the same path. You can either define new paths for each of them like `/myGet/entity`, `/myGet/`, `/myGet/differentParam`; or use a single path as `/myGet/` and check the query params as following:

```
@GET  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@TypeHint(TagSets.class)
public Response getTagSets(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

       ...

       if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
           // then you have no query params, implement as there are no query params
       } else {
           String queryParam = request.getQueryString();
           // check queryParam, and add another if else statements, implement
       }

       ...

}
```

Comment: So the answer is still the same. There is no way to do what I want with Jersey, is there a way to do it with any other framework?

Comment: i did not use any other web service frameworks so cannot tell anything about them but it is really interesting the fact that you want to switch to a completely new framework instead of implementing a few more lines in a method

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions, 1: you have no idea the volume of my webapp, this might as well be just a POC. 2: A part of this question is for learning and not just solving this problem.

Comment: About learning I agree with you, I am also curious about the answer though

Comment: "You last voted on this question 
23 hours ago 
Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited"

Comment: *"A resource is uniquely defined by its **path**, and not by its params."* - Yes, but that does not necessarily mean it should be uniquely identified by a single **method**.

Comment: But JAXrs does support content negotiation , I'm not sure why param negotiation is not supported, did you actually test this ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is as described in the comments. You can use a single method which declares all query params and then based on values (exists or not), calls the correct method.

(Work around approach)
If all you want is to expose a single endpoint with multiple query param to the client and code implementation doesn't matter, you can use interceptors. read the query param and modify URI to direct it to proper method.